# Using a boolean to compares two dataframes, and creating a subset dataframe from that boolean

Tags: python, pandas, boolean, subset

This is a little hard for me to explain so I will do my best.
I'm playing around with the titanic dataset for survivors and the column "Cabin" had a lot of missing values. So I decided to focus on the correlation between "Cabin" and "Fare" and created a new dataframe called "Fare_sort", which is just these two columns with "Fare" being sorted .

Here is a "head" from the dataset "Fare_sort":

```
  Fare            Cabin
732  0.0000          NaN
413  0.0000          NaN
806  0.0000          A36
266  0.0000          NaN
633  0.0000          NaN
674  0.0000          NaN
815  0.0000         B102
372  0.0000  B52 B54 B56
21   3.1708          NaN
378  4.0125          NaN
872  5.0000  B51 B53 B55
```

Here is tail

```
527  221.7792              C95        
114  221.7792          C55 C57         
81   221.7792          C55 C57        
156  221.7792              C97        
716  227.5250              C45         
380  227.5250              NaN       
557  227.5250              NaN         
700  227.5250          C62 C64        
299  247.5208          B58 B60          
118  247.5208          B58 B60          
184  247.5208          B58 B60         
375  262.3750              NaN          
24   262.3750  B57 B59 B63 B66          
742  262.3750  B57 B59 B63 B66         
59   262.3750              B61
```

Then I created another database consisting only the rows where "Cabin" has values and called it Overview.

```
Overview =Fare_sort[Fare_sort.Cabin.notnull()==True]
```

So the head of Overview looks something like this:

```
     Fare        Cabin  
806   0.0          A36       
815   0.0         B102       
372   0.0  B52 B54 B56      
263   0.0          B94         
872   5.0  B51 B53 B55
```

What Im trying to do now is create another dataframe which compares the items of column 'Fare' from dataframe "Overview" to the original dataframe 'Fare_sort's  "Fare" column, and if  Overview.Fare == Fare_sort.Fare, I want to append that row from Fare_sort (so both Fare and Cabin will be added)to the newly created dataframe, df.

So from the items posted above the new dataframe would look like this:

```
 Fare            Cabin
732  0.0000          NaN
413  0.0000          NaN
806  0.0000          A36
266  0.0000          NaN
633  0.0000          NaN
674  0.0000          NaN
815  0.0000         B102
372  0.0000  B52 B54 B56
872  5.0000  B51 B53 B55
```

So, essentially,"Fare" prices where "Cabin" had at least one value, are being added to the new dataframe.

I tried playing around with this code

```
    for i in Overview.Fare:
        if i == Fare_sort.Fare:
            df = df.append(Fare_sort.Fare)
```

But this code produced errors.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this any different from querying for entries with non-null `Cabin` or zero `Fare`? I.e., `Fare_sort.query('Cabin==Cabin or Fare==0.0')`

Comment: The database is pretty big so there are areas other besides "Fare ==0.0" where, non_null "Cabin" will result in a "Fare" value which has many there are multiples items of that "Fare" value.  I will edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: My previous comment has a typo and I can't seem to edit it so: The database is pretty big so there are areas other besides "Fare ==0.0" where, non_null "Cabin" will result in a "Fare" value which has  multiple items at that "Fare" value.  I will edit the question to make it more clear. I updated the question with a tail version, so you can see more entries.